# PHP retrieving usernames from my database and then putting them into an array

Tags: php, html

So I've been working on a little automatic payment system, and I'm almost done! My customers will get their account upgraded automatically after payment, but I have a slight problem.

I'm currently manually adding their username to an array which changes their username style to distinguish their rank.

I would like to know how to make it retrieve and successful go into an array which will then be called and show their new username.

Here is my code for retrieving usernames and then putting into an array:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "changed", "changed", "changed")or die(mysqli_error());
$listmembers = $db->query("SELECT * FROM members")or die(mysqli_error());

$names = array();
while($listnames = $listmembers->fetch_assoc()) {
$names[] = "'" . $listnames['username'];
}
$newname = explode("\", ", $names);
```

Okay and this is what my array code looks like

> $members = array($newname);

And this is the code changing their rank:

> if(in_array(strtolower($rows['received']), $members)) {
>   $user =  "**" . ucfirst($rows['received']) . "**";
>   }

If anyone cold help me, i'd appreciate it.

Comment: why there is "'" . in while loop.?

Comment: you can't explode an array($name) - explode returns an array

Comment: Yes. @Philipp is correct. You cannot explode an array

Comment: use [array_push](http://php.net/array_push) to add value into array

Comment: It still doesn't work ;/

Answer (score 0):

Turn warnings on to see a few of your mistakes..

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "changed", "changed", "changed")or die(mysqli_error());
$listmembers = $db->query("SELECT * FROM members")or die(mysqli_error());

$names = array();
while($listnames = $listmembers->fetch_assoc()) {
    $names[] = $listnames['username'];
}
```

and later something like this..

```
if(in_array(strtolower($rows['received']), $names)) {
    $user =  "<font color=\"lime\"><b>" . ucfirst($rows['received']) . "</b></font>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, however I still haven't got my issue resolved.

Comment: And whats your issue!? Error message, wrong behavior or something else?

Comment: This is my errror:
$names = $listmembers->fetch_all();

It gives me: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()

Answer (score 0):

why you don't fetch array directly from database?

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "changed", "changed", "changed")or die(mysqli_error());
$listmembers = $db->query("SELECT username FROM members")or die(mysqli_error());

$names = $listmembers->fetch_all();
```

and then:

```
foreach ( $names as $username ) {
    if ( strtolower($rows['received']) == $username[0] ) {
        $user = ucfirst($rows['received']);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because names is a 2-dim array and in_array can't search in 2-dim arrays..